# My jupyter notebook kernel often dies from this pygame code

Tags: python, pygame, jupyter-notebook

I wrote a pygame code like this.

```
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Test")
black = (0, 0, 0)
sysfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)
win.fill((255, 255, 255))

running = True
while running:
    win.fill((255, 255, 255))
    digit = sysfont.render("Test", 1, black)
    win.blit(digit, (50, 50))
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            
pygame.quit()
```

So That's just to create a window and show some text on it.
I runned it on Jupyter Notebook and it worked. but when I closed the window and tried to run it again, a window came up but closed of itself and Jupyter said "The kernel appears to have died."
This happened again and again. I runned it, it worked. but I rerunned it, it failed. Is there anything wrong with this code?

Comment: It doesn't `import pygame`, but other than that, there's nothing wrong.  It works for me here (not Jupyter)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I stopped running it on jupyter and run it now on VS code. So far there's no issue here. so it might be a problem with anaconda or jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an issue with Anaconda, as the same issue has been faced by me in spyder kernel. For spyder it restarts the kernel, which is a little time taking but i don't think there exists a solution for the same.

I hope you're safe in this time of an ongoing pandemic!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you are right. it might be a problem with anaconda. I'm running it on VS code, and there's no issue happening so far.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and I kind of addressed it by stopping the kernel instead of exiting the pygame. when I stop the kernel, the pygame windows also stoped and in the next run, it starts without killing the kernel.
Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

I bypassed this problem by adding `%reset -f` at the first line before all the import statements.  I can run and close the window without the dead kernel prompt.  Hopefully this helps people looking for this kind of solution.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and adding the part in asterisks, allowed me to close the game window, without restarting the kernel.

```
run = True
while run:
    key = None
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            key = event.key
            
        **if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()**

    pygame.display.update()
```